# How to delete element without knowing it's id, just order in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have database table **requests:**

```
+----+---------+-----------------+--------+
| id | user_id | bicycle_type_id | height |
+----+---------+-----------------+--------+
```

And **one** user can have **many** records in this table. Ofcourse those record will have different id's.

When i displaying (in front-end) list of items, it is independent from `id` column in database, so the list always starts from 1, then 2 ... and so on. So, as a function argument, i get array of ID's (which are id's in the List on front-end, not in the database. Like number in the sequence) of the records i need to delete.

**Important** - I *CAN'T* change front-end

How can i preform query to delete elements when i only know their id in `ASC` order (their sequence number), which are unrelated from actual id's in the table?

Comment: yuk. That could be horribly unreliable - suppose that rows are added/deleted in between the initial data being returned to the front-end and the delete being requested - you can't rely on these sequence numbers for anything in that situation. Either strongly insist that the front-end is changed so it knows the real IDs (they need not be visible to users), or the only other thing I can think of is you'd have to somehow cache the initial resultset that was given to the front end, mapping the sequence at that time to the IDs, and then match the cached version to the deletion request coming back.

Comment: I don't get this. How can the IDs not be known? You show data from the table and every record in this table has an ID. So even when you don't *show* this ID, it still exists and you can use it as a reference. Or are you saying that you only watch the screen, see what is shown (data without ID) and then you type a delete statement based on what you see?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner YES. It's not a web site and not even close to that. That is why o can't change this behaviour

Comment: you want us to `goochel` (dutch word for doing magic) instead of google

Comment: @davejal i'm not that type of person who are asking questions before googling. I spent last 2 hours trying to figure it out and still no progress. That is why i;m here.

Comment: I didn't mean you have to google, I meant you want us to do magic. See the comment by @ThorstenKettner , then you'll know what I mean

Comment: @davejal I answered his question - YES. It's my case.

Comment: Is it possible that you can uniquely identify the record using the other values, without requiring the id?

Answer (score 0):

For example if you want to delete the 12th row in the table:

```
DELETE FROM requests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 11
```

To delete the 5th row:

```
DELETE FROM requests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
```

To delete the 34th row:

```
DELETE FROM requests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 33
```

I would advise you make a table copy and test on the copy first.

OR

Try the following and see if you get the right row that you want to delete.

```
SELECT FROM requests ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
```

Comment: In multiuser environment it will eventually delete wrong rows because DELETE .. OFFSET 11 will run on other data compared to the moment data were selected  and 11 picked up by the front end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe MySQL supports `OFFSET` in the `LIMIT` clause for `DELETE`.

You can do this as:

```
delete requests r join
       (select r2.*
        from requests r2
        order by id
        offset 11 limit 1
       ) rr
       on r.id = rr.id;
```

I would suggest a couple of things in addition:

- Lock the entire table.  Two deletes running at the same time could interfere with each other.
- Ensure that `id` is auto-increment, so new values are always larger than previous values (hence, `insert`s won't interfere with `delete`s).